# RSS for Slashdot mobile

Tags: rss, feeds

I would like to subscribe to slashdot articles under mobile category only (http://mobile.slashdot.org/). But their RSS link (http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot) gives articles from all categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slashdot's rss feed for the mobile section only:

http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdotmobile

For further reference on creating section-only feeds, refer to this page: http://slashdot.org/faq/feeds.shtml